# Tableau how to convert a dimension into a datetime

Tags: datetime, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau 9.0, I am trying to calculate service outage time.  I have 2 dimensions to work with -start time and an end time. When I look at the values they are in this format:

Example:

```
Outage Start:       Outage End: 
1452005400          1,452,011,400
```

Ideally I'd like to convert the current format to a datetime so that I work with it to find the outage time down to seconds.

Does any one know how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what EPOCH format you use, this formula will do the trick:

```
DATEADD('second', [EPOCH FORMAT TIME], DATE('1/1/1970'))
```

For your example value of **1452011400** will return Jan 5, 2016 - 4.30pm.

[image: Tableau Screenshot of EPOCH time format conversion]

Keep in mind there are two EPOCH formats, so make sure you use the correct one: The *Unix* epoch is typically 1/1/1970, while the *Microsoft* COM epoch is 12/30/1899.

I have used Unix format in my example above (the last argument to *DATEADD* funciton).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I couldn't figure out what format it was in.  Also I keep getting an oracle error when I do the above : Oracle database error 1843: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: In Tableau or Oracle?

Comment: You can simplify slightly using the format for date literals, #1/1/1970#. That # sign syntax Tableau borrowed from MS Access